# how to retrieve specific web service response from the server

Tags: java, .net, soap, soapui, soap-client

Web service provider has provided us(Client) a wsdl to use their service and consume data. Our requirement is, we just need specific node value called "CHASE", see below test data. We don't want to get all records of info and corresponding nodes in the response.

Here is an example that we have tested in SOAPUI tool. Please suggest and help us how can we frame the web service request technically from the URL provided(http://host:port/ValueMappingInService/ValueMappingInImplBean)? Is it at all possible to drill down the request and get specific response from client side?

Web service Request:-

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:bas="http://sap.com/xi/BASIS">
  <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bas:ValueMappingReadRequest>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ReadContext>User</ReadContext>
    <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
     <ValueMappingID>c44f541f-c8ac-11e8-86e5-0050569d98cc</ValueMappingID>
  </bas:ValueMappingReadRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

 Web service Response:-

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP- 
 ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns2:ValueMappingReadResponse xmlns:ns2="http://sap.com/xi/BASIS">
         <ValueMapping>
           <MasterLanguage>EN</MasterLanguage>
            <AdministrativeData>
           <ResponsibleUserAccountID>gdonna</ResponsibleUserAccountID>
           <LastChangeUserAccountID>gdonna</LastChangeUserAccountID>
           <LastChangeDateTime>2018-10-05T09:47:38.237-05:00</LastChangeDateTime>
           <FolderPathID>/</FolderPathID>
        </AdministrativeData>
        <ValueMappingID>c44f541f-c8ac-11e8-86e5-0050569d98cc</ValueMappingID>
        <GroupName>Mercedes</GroupName>
        <Representation schemeAgencyID="LOC_BANK" schemeID="BANK">CHASE</Representation>
        <Representation schemeAgencyID="LOC_SITE" schemeID="DIR">comm/as2/chase/receive/</Representation>
        <Representation schemeAgencyID="LOC_COUNTRY" schemeID="CODE">US</Representation>
     </ValueMapping>
     <LogMessageCollection/>
  </ns2:ValueMappingReadResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
 </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Would any expert answer my question?

Comment: I would love to help, but I'm not sure what it is you need. From your phrasing, it sounds to me, like you want a specific response, but your description makes it sound like you already have the response you need, but you would like to just pick one specific value from that response...?

Comment: You want some way to fetch the value of the XML entity, that in your example has the value CHASE...?

Comment: Yes, I want to fetch a specific value from an entity as we don't want enitre XML payload. How can I frame a drill down url from this url http://host:port/ValueMappingInService/ValueMappingInImplBean?

Comment: My UI screen is having just 3 controls which will feed this information to other object. 1) which captures web service url request, 2) Submit button, 3) web service response value(32 characters).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Groovy Script. I really like the features of the XMLSlurper, which lets me ignore the namespaces if/when they change.

Just add a new Groovy Script teststep, and put this into it. You just need to adjust the name of your Soap Request teststep, which should be placed just before this teststep.

```
/** The name should be modified to match the request/response you want to validate */
def holder =  new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context ).getXmlHolder("The Name Of Your Soap Request TestStep#Response")
def response = new XmlSlurper().parseText(holder.getXml())
for (def element : response.Body.ValueMappingReadResponse.ValueMapping.Representation) 
{
   log.info element
   log.info element.@'schemeAgencyID'
}
```